# How To Convert Project Windows Phone Application inTo Executable File ?(Works on Mobile)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7-emulator

i want to create executable(.exe / msi ) file for my windows 7 phone application.

So that it works on Mobile ..

I designed a program on the Visual Studio 2010 for Windows Phone.

Please help me ..

thanks

Answer (score 0):

In order to deploy a program from visual studio onto your phone, you need to run the Zune software and connect your windows phone.  Then in visual studio, you can select your windows phone in the build target drop down (next to the debug+run button in the tool bar).

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting to install Windows Phone 7 apps on Windows Mobile 6, it can't be done. WP7 is not backward compatible with WM6, nor is WM6 forward compatible with WP7.

If you're wanting to create an installer for users to download and install your app on their WP7 device, it can be done but you likely won't have much success. Out-of-the-box WP7 devices are locked to the Zune Marketplace, so that apps can only be installed via the Marketplace. Some folks have unlocked phones, either developer unlocked or homebrewed. Developer unlocking a device requires registration as a developer with Microsoft, which costs USD$99/year (or waived with a student DreamSpark account). There was a homebrew program called Chevron that was blessed but not supported by Microsoft; this program has been cancelled. The percentage of unlocked phones in the wild is very small.

If you just want to install your app on your phone, see LiquidAsh's answer. But you're phone will still need to be unlocked, most likely by registering with Microsoft.